# Choosing colors for highlight in ArcGIS JS API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the code that the documentation provides here:

```
require(["esri/views/View"], (View) => {
view.on("click", function(event){
  view.hitTest(event).then(function(response){
    if (response.results.length) {
      let graphic = response.results.filter(function (result) {
        return result.graphic.layer === states;
      })[0].graphic;
    
     view.whenLayerView(graphic.layer).then(function(layerView){
       layerView.highlight(graphic);    
     });
    }
  });
});
});
```

I want to know how I could adjust the color based on the currently selected color. For example, how would I detect the current highlighted color and base the new one off of that.
For example:

```
if (color == currentColor) {
  highlightOptions = {
    new color for highlightOptions 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current select color from `view.highlightOptions.color` property and you can set select color by changing value of this property.

Code below increments current blue channel of select color for clicked feature on each click by 20:

```
const view = new SceneView({
  map: webScene,
  container: "viewDiv",
  highlightOptions: {
    color: [255, 0, 0],
    fillOpacity: 0.4
  }
});

view.on("click", function(event){
  view.hitTest(event).then(function(response){
    if (response.results.length) {
      let graphic = response.results.filter(function (result) {
        return result.graphic.layer.declaredClass == "esri.layers.FeatureLayer";
      })[0].graphic;
    
      view.whenLayerView(graphic.layer).then(function(layerView) {
        var color = view.highlightOptions.color;
        var blue = color.b + 20;
        if (blue > 255) blue = 0;
        view.highlightOptions = {
          color: [255, 0, blue]
       };
       layerView.highlight(graphic);    
     });
    }
  });
});
```